# The "filter" link is too high in the review queue interface

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

Usually, the "filter" link in review queues is aligned with the queue's title, but currently, it's pushed up quite a bit:

[image: filter link is too high]

This happens in all queues on the sites I checked (Super User and Stack Overflow).

I'm using Google Chrome 50.0.2661.94 on 64-bit Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed, it will be live after our next production build.